# signal.SIGALRM with uwsgi

Tags: python, timeout, signals, uwsgi

I run django with uwsgi server.
My code contains many api calls with urllib2 like this:

```
with closing(urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=1)) as f:
    content = f.read()
```

Even when I set socket timeout I see request takes more seconds that I'd like. I guess it happens because timeout limits socket connection but not data reading.

And I want to limit this code block. Tried to achieve it with `signal.SIGALRM` but it doesn't work with uwsgi (I run without `enable-threads`). But it works with Apache+mod_wsgi. Thread timeout looks unreliable.

No errors, SIGALRM is just ignored either harakiri mode or not.
I'm not good in reading C source code but the reason of such behavior [here](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/gateway.c#L73).

Comment: I had a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536469/stopping-a-function-in-python-using-a-timeout

Answer (score 8):

Python compiled with thread support does not call custom signal handlers [in its threads or `fork()`s](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.9/Modules/signalmodule.c#l197) unless it is reinitialized with [`PyOS_AfterFork()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.9/Modules/signalmodule.c#l1008), which normally happens in [`os.fork()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.9/Modules/posixmodule.c#l3835), but strangely uwsgi does not do this by default. However, it provides an option [`--py-call-osafterfork`](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/2.0.11.2/plugins/python/python_plugin.c#L171), with which uwsgi slaves can handle signals, including `SIGALRM`.

Answer (score 2):

do not use UNIX signals for such things, they are basically unreliable. Harakiri mode has a "userlevel" conterpart:

```
uwsgi.set_user_harakiri(10)
with closing(urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=1)) as f:
    content = f.read()
uwsgi.set_user_harakiri(0)
```

Comment: How can I catch harakiri exception?

Comment: you can't as the worker will be reloaded if the function is blocked for more than 10 seconds (or whatever value you set)

Comment: Actually it's not what I'm looking for =(

Comment: then do not use urllib but something like curl that allows you better control over timeouts. I now understand you wanted to use an ALARM to inject an exception in the python VM: this is extremely bad and prone to every kind of error :)