# How to add a timeout to a Python 3 RegEx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, timeout, python-re

I have a regex that might take a long time to execute, despite my best efforts at optimization. I want to be able to interrupt it in the cases where it stalls, and proceed with the rest of the program

Other languages like C# have a Timeout property for the Regex execution and I am wondering why Python 3 seems to not have the same approach.

Internally Python 3 have a sort of maximum time of execution, because after a long time the regex abort and the execution go ahead. Is it true?

I would like to analyze that question on python 3 and to use a platform independent approach (I saw decorator that work only on NIX OSs with Signals...)

Maybe the answer is to manage this problem using a more general approach on how to stop function in Python, like in [How to add a timeout to a function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196999) or [Stopping a function in Python using a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536469).

How can I implement such a timeout?

Comment: No because in the solution there is a decorator that is system dependent. Moreover the post is not clear on what version of python regards. Maybe in python 3 there is a different approach.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew rather, that question is an inferior duplicate of one of the ones OP found.

Comment: Since there clearly is not any such functionality built into the standard library regex, there are three ways to interpret the question: 1) "Why not?" -> not suitable for the site; we aren't mind-readers, and we don't deal in the subjective. 2) "What third-party library can I use instead?" -> explicitly off topic; we don't do such recommendations. 3) "How can I implement it myself?" -> there is nothing special about implementing a timeout simply because the task being timed-out is a regex operation; OP already found a post with a generic solution, or at least an attempt.

Comment: So that makes this question a duplicate, if it's suitable at all. If there are any flaws in existing answers at the now-linked duplicate, they should be corrected over there, perhaps with new, better answers. I also closed the other question OP found, as well as the other candidate duplicate, as duplicates of that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding why the built-in `re` module for Python doesn't have the same timeout approach as C#- Tim Peters has commented on this matter in a [now-closed issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue46627#msg412493):

> Introducing some kind of optional timeout is too involved to just drop in without significant discussion and design effort first.

> My first take: it wouldn't really help, because nobody would use it until after it was too late.

However, there is a public [PyPI module called `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) which aims to provide complete backwards compatibility with the `re` module, while offering more complex functionality (such as timeouts). Here is a snippet directly from their documentation that shows how to use it:

> The matching methods and functions support timeouts. The timeout (in seconds) applies to the entire operation:

```py
>>> from time import sleep
>>>
>>> def fast_replace(m):
...     return 'X'
...
>>> def slow_replace(m):
...     sleep(0.5)
...     return 'X'
...
>>> regex.sub(r'[a-z]', fast_replace, 'abcde', timeout=2)
'XXXXX'
>>> regex.sub(r'[a-z]', slow_replace, 'abcde', timeout=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\regex\regex.py", line 278, in sub
    return pat.sub(repl, string, count, pos, endpos, concurrent, timeout)
TimeoutError: regex timed out
```

The timeout functionality in this module is great, because it is [wired directly into the main matching loop](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/blob/cc392629b28ed0aeb8bf6d46f826ff9e87aac551/regex_3/_regex.c#L11745) (see `safe_check_cancel`), and is not based on any platform-dependent solution, such as leveraging the `signal` module.